# Specifying a folder to filter Ansible Dynamic inventory for VMware

Tags: vmware-vsphere, ansible

I want to use the [vmware_inventory.py dynamic inventory script](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/contrib/inventory/vmware_inventory.py) with Ansible to generate an inventory based on my VMware guests.

However, my Vsphere cluster has many hosts running on it which I do not with to have included in the inventory, or manage with Ansible.  In the vmware_inventory.ini configuration I see the following line:

```
#host_filters={{ guest.gueststate == "running" }}
```

Which looks like it would be useful for filtering only the guests I wish to manage.  However, I can't see where the possible values for this field are documented.  Ideally, I'd use this in conjunction with the `groupby_patterns` configuration to get an inventory which has groups corresponding to their folder in Vsphere.

How can I specify that I only want to load hosts into my inventory that are in a specific folder, or have a prefix in their name, or have some other property assigned to them?

EDIT: this could also be a tag

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that I needed to first modify the skip_keys parameter as such

```
skip_keys = declaredalarmstate,disabledmethod,dynamicproperty,dynamictype,environmentbrowser,managedby,childtype,resourceconfig
```

(removing parent, so that key is no longer skipped)

Now, I can specify a filter like this:

```
host_filters={{ parent.name == "MyFolderName"}}
```

And it will return all machines under the folder **MyFolderName** in VSphere